# How to show CircularProgressIndicator() from a child widget in the parent?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a network call from child stateful widget. For that, I need to show CircularProgressIndicator in parent widget containing the Scaffold. Is there any way to show it?

Parent Widget:

```
class OrderDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
  _OrderDetailPageState createState() => _OrderDetailPageState();

}

class _OrderDetailPageState extends State<OrderDetailPage> {
    bool isloading = false;

    Widget build(BuildContext context){
       return Scaffold(body: isLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator() : Container(
          child: ChildWidget()
      ));
    }
}
```

Child:

```
class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ChildWidgetState createState() => ChildWidgetState();
}

class ChildWidgetState extends State<OrderDetailPage> {
  return Center(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () { // need to make isloading in parent widget to true and false})
}
```

Comment: yes there is a way

Comment: yes u can do that. Share the code in your question then i can help you

Comment: @Niteesh Code can't be shared due to security reasons. Both parent and child are stateful widgets. Can we show it with key passed to child widget?

Comment: you are suppose to create simple reproducible code here when asking question which focus on the problem you are having. Please see how to ask question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @LonelyWolf provided a sample code

Comment: use future builder https://fluttercentral.com/Articles/Post/1082/Show_loading_while_performing_an_operation_in_Flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of passing `State` up into the Widget Tree.

Passing a callback function from parent to child:

```
class OrderDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
  _OrderDetailPageState createState() => _OrderDetailPageState();

}

class _OrderDetailPageState extends State<OrderDetailPage> {
    bool isloading = false;
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
       return Scaffold(body: isLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator() : Container(
          child: ChildWidget(callback: () => setState(() => isLoading = !isLoading))
      ));
    }
}
```

Child:

```
class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ChildWidget({this.callback});
  @override
  ChildWidgetState createState() => ChildWidgetState();
}

class ChildWidgetState extends State<OrderDetailPage> {
  return Center(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () { 
   widget.callback();
}
```

The late alternative is to use a State Management Solution like `InheritedWidget` , the `Provider` Package or one of many others out there.